# Rotating vertical pole setup

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, bearings

software person here, venturing for the first time in the design of a mechanical system for a hobby project. Please note I have some experience in disassembling, fixing, reassembling mechanical systems, but design my own is a whole other thing.

In practice, I would need a motor (that I know how to control) to rotate a vertical pole, or mast. The motor has a wormgear reduction box similar to this:

[image: wormgear DC motor]

What I'd like to avoid is to put off-axis strain on the motor in case the pole is pushed sideways; also, the pole should be able to rotate as freely as possible to the torque from the motor does not have to be excessive. The weight pushing down from the pole should also be taken care of.

My first intuitive approach would be to use two thrust bearing devices similar to this:

[image]

so that the mast will be constrained on its axis and also the weight supported. I'd mount a gear around the mast with the motor with a smaller gear on its output shaft.

Any advice, should I consider anything else? Please, let me know if a more comprehensive drawing is needed to communicate what I want to achieve, I'll try to put one together.

Comment: why not just buy an old-school TV antenna rotator and hack its control circuit?

Comment: Because by extension, why make a hobby project at all when I could just sit on the couch and watch TV :)
What I mean is, compared to computer programming and electrical, my mechanical experience is very low, so I started thinking about a project like this.

I already own a huge rotator https://static.dxengineering.com/global/images/prod/xlarge/ysu-g-2800dxa_xl.jpg

Comment: You might better isolate the motor from the shaft with a belt, but you'd want to make sure it's reasonably easy to change the belt.

Comment: Alessio, I am a retired mechanical engineer and the last three places I worked had no money for tooling- so I had to buy junk machinery and hack it into production machinery- so this is a habit of mine, by the way I am KI7KXK in Corvallis Oregon

Comment: @TimWescott as I'm learning could you describe quickly why a belt solution would offer advantages? Yeah the mounting system and a way to release tension may not be trivial

Comment: @nielsnielsen Yeah I understand, but you were already an accomplished mechanical engineer, so I'm pretty sure you did the right thing there!